# Persistent object in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save the data objects, this time using CoreData. Right now, the classes look like this:

```
class Game: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var matches: NSOrderedSet

}

class Match: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: String
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var players: NSOrderedSet
    @NSManaged var parentGame: Game

}

class Player: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var history: String
    @NSManaged var id: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var totalScore: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var parentMatch: Match

}
```

So the Game class has an NSOrderedSet that's supposed to hold a bunch of Match objects, and so on. So using CoreData, how do I add Matches into the Set in the Game class, and Players into the matches? And then how do I configure them once they are added?

Comment: You need to use Core Data for this. There are alternatives like Realm, but Core Data is really great to learn.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: What problem were you having with NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't say:

> making my classes inherit from NSCoding and NSObject

You inherit from `NSObject` and implement `NSCoding` protocol.

2. If you want to store data into `NSUserDefaults` you need encode and decode each property. http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: Also, you can only encode property list types in NSUserDefaults. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44